# errors when trying to build in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, readline

Considering none of the code is my own, I feel helpless. It's an open source tool, and I can't use it.

This is the tool : http://www.gnucap.org/devel/gnucap-2013-04-23.tar.gz

And these are the errors I get when building on Cygwin (Win 7, 64b) :

```
$ ./configure
Configuring gnucap using --prefix=/usr/local
include
lib
In file included from /usr/include/readline/readline.h:35:0,
                 from test_readline.cc:2:
/usr/include/readline/rltypedefs.h:64:28: error: typedef ‘rl_getc_func_t’ is initialized (use decltype instead)
 typedef int rl_getc_func_t PARAMS((FILE *));
                            ^
/usr/include/readline/rltypedefs.h:64:28: error: ‘FILE’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/readline/rltypedefs.h:64:28: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
 typedef int rl_getc_func_t PARAMS((FILE *));
                            ^
/usr/include/readline/readline.h:419:20: error: ‘FILE’ was not declared in this scope
 extern int rl_getc PARAMS((FILE *));
                    ^
/usr/include/readline/readline.h:419:20: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
 extern int rl_getc PARAMS((FILE *));
                    ^
In file included from test_readline.cc:2:0:
/usr/include/readline/readline.h:542:8: error: ‘FILE’ does not name a type
 extern FILE *rl_instream;
        ^
/usr/include/readline/readline.h:543:8: error: ‘FILE’ does not name a type
 extern FILE *rl_outstream;
        ^
/usr/include/readline/readline.h:565:8: error: ‘rl_getc_func_t’ does not name a type
 extern rl_getc_func_t *rl_getc_function;
        ^
/usr/include/readline/readline.h:867:3: error: ‘FILE’ does not name a type
   FILE *inf;
   ^
/usr/include/readline/readline.h:868:3: error: ‘FILE’ does not name a type
   FILE *outf;
   ^
either libtermcap or libreadline is missing - not using readline
modelgen
main
apps
In file included from /usr/include/readline/readline.h:35:0,
                 from test_readline.cc:2:
/usr/include/readline/rltypedefs.h:64:28: error: typedef ‘rl_getc_func_t’ is initialized (use decltype instead)
 typedef int rl_getc_func_t PARAMS((FILE *));
                            ^
/usr/include/readline/rltypedefs.h:64:28: error: ‘FILE’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/readline/rltypedefs.h:64:28: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
 typedef int rl_getc_func_t PARAMS((FILE *));
                            ^
/usr/include/readline/readline.h:419:20: error: ‘FILE’ was not declared in this scope
 extern int rl_getc PARAMS((FILE *));
                    ^
/usr/include/readline/readline.h:419:20: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
 extern int rl_getc PARAMS((FILE *));
                    ^
In file included from test_readline.cc:2:0:
/usr/include/readline/readline.h:542:8: error: ‘FILE’ does not name a type
 extern FILE *rl_instream;
        ^
/usr/include/readline/readline.h:543:8: error: ‘FILE’ does not name a type
 extern FILE *rl_outstream;
        ^
/usr/include/readline/readline.h:565:8: error: ‘rl_getc_func_t’ does not name a type
 extern rl_getc_func_t *rl_getc_function;
        ^
/usr/include/readline/readline.h:867:3: error: ‘FILE’ does not name a type
   FILE *inf;
   ^
/usr/include/readline/readline.h:868:3: error: ‘FILE’ does not name a type
   FILE *outf;
   ^
either libtermcap or libreadline is missing - not using readline
done
```

Any help will be great. I feel helpless. If you can suggest resources so I can learn to fix such errors on my own, that would be teaching me how to fish..

Comment: I'd suggest reporting on their bug-gnucap mailing list.  http://savannah.gnu.org/mail/?group_id=562.

Answer (score 3):

You have to include `stdio.h` in `lib/test_readline.cc` to define `FILE`.

Comment: This seems like an outright bug in readline, and it's still present today in RHEL7.  Any file which includes readline needs to include stdio.h first.